# Grouping multiple dimension's values into one value in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

While developing a dashboard in Tableau 10, I'm using SSAS Tabular model as my data source.

One of my dimensions is called "Game" and it have many values.

I want to group *some* of those values into one value with a new name.

For example, let's say I have the following values under "Game" dimension:

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D
5. E

And I want to group values A, B and C into new value named "F" so "Game" (or any other dimension) will posses values:

1. D
2. E
3. F (grouping of A, B and C)

The end goal is, of course, to present some measures for each game, and aggregate those measures for A, B and C together so they'll be displayed *aggregated* under "F".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just create a Group of the values in the *Game* dimension:

1. Right-click on *Game* dimension => Create => Group...
2. Group the values you want to have grouped, name the group as you
   want, and leave all values, which should remain as they are,
   ungrouped.
3. Make sure to leave the *Include 'Other'* checkbox unchecked. Then
   save.

This group should return all values as you need them. New values will be returned as separate values, unless you manually ad them to a group in the *'Game'* Group.